# cURL returns different result

Tags: php, curl

The below function returns different result than that actually we render the page directly.

What would be the issue?

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1)Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using when accessing it directly?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your accessing it with one browser, but your setting the `$useragent` to another. The external site might be returning different data depending on the useragent

Comment: is there any way to get contents of external site that does not depend on the useragent?

Comment: Sure, just don't use `$useragent`.

Comment: still the problem persists. I tried to get google search result by this. It gives a different count number and output like this "2,00,000 RESULTS" , which is different from original "of 5,00,000 RESULTS"

Comment: Oh, then that's a different story. If you're trying to access Google via cURL, you're going to run into issues. They have been known to return fake data when they think someone is trying to scrape SERPS

Comment: Scraping google is against their TOS anyways... http://www.google.ca/intl/en/policies/terms/archive/20070416/    Section 5.3